# extract sha-1 and sha-256 keys for release apk with flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, release, sha

i run this command :

```
E:\cihan_university\mobile_programming\mp\courses_app\android>gradlew signinReport
```

in order to get sha-1 and sha-256 for release mode .... my project is connected with firebase, and i have used the phone auth..... but which one should use here? i got like this result:

```
  Welcome to Gradle 6.7!
    
    Here are the highlights of this release:
     - File system watching is ready for production use
     - Declare the version of Java your build requires
     - Java 15 support
    
    For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html
    
    Starting a Gradle Daemon, 10 busy and 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
    
    > Configure project :app
    WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
    It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
    You will no longer be able to disable R8
    
    > Configure project :firebase_auth
    WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
    It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
    You will no longer be able to disable R8
    
    > Task :advance_pdf_viewer:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :app:signingReport
    Variant: debug
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: release
    Config: release
    Store: C:\Users\kh\enycript\upload-keystore.jks
    Alias: upload
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Thursday, November 5, 2048
    ----------
    Variant: profile
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: release
    Store: C:\Users\kh\enycript\upload-keystore.jks
    Alias: upload
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Thursday, November 5, 2048
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :cloud_firestore:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :firebase_auth:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :firebase_core:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :flutter_inappwebview:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    > Task :path_provider:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    ----------
    
    > Task :sqflite:signingReport
    Variant: debugAndroidTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
    MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: debugUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: releaseUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    Variant: profileUnitTest
    Config: debug
    Store: C:\Users\kh\.android\debug.keystore
    Alias: AndroidDebugKey
   MD5: ##################################
    SHA1: ##################################
    SHA-256: ##################################
    Valid until: Wednesday, March 15, 2051
    ----------
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:c
    ommand_line_warnings
    
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 58s
    8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
    E:\cihan_university\mobile_programming\mp\courses_app\android>cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    
    E:\cihan_university\mobile_programming\mp\courses_app\android>cd..
    
    E:\cihan_university\mobile_programming\mp\courses_app>cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: All release and debug keys should be same as I remember. On release mode you can pass a release mode key only.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sha-1 and sha-256 key, you need to go the [project directory]/android. then run this command `./gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score -1):

when I try to find it I have some error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file `'C:\Users\negar\android\settings.gradle' line: 20`
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.

> Could not read script `'C:\Users\negar\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.13.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle'` as it does not exist.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

Comment: make sure you are in the flutter project directory. also when you give an answer just R&D  of this topic also don't add errors or something wrong in the answer.